# Why Yii2 doesn't work from subdirectory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

I have a small site on yii2, but it doesn't work from subdirectory. (site.com/**yii**). I think that problem in `.htaccess`, but I can't repair it. 
My `.htaccess` in root is standart for yii2:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

And `.htaccess` in web directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

I tried set `RewriteBase` to subdir, but no result.

Comment: What's exacly means `doesn't work`? How the virtual hosts are set?

Comment: return 404 error. If i add RewriteBase return 500 error. 
I know what this errors means, but i cant fix it

Comment: Check the logs for the 500. Is it yii'2 404 or apache/nginx 404? Give us some information

Comment: 404 is server error.